# css grid align vertically and horizontally without disturbing background color or image

Tags: css, css-grid

i created .container with some color & in that container header with some other color and text. now i want to center text. i am able to do that with grid but problem is my header color (background color of header) shrink to vertically and horizontally center too. i want only text to get in center not the color. hope i explained clearly. plz explain me how i can achieve that. 
(

i am using visual studio. align-item align-content align-self(on header)justify-item,content,self nothing working for me plz clear my confusion

i need only text in center if i put image or logo that in center. i dont want background image to be compromise and i wanna use grid only.
i tried 6 grid commands align-item align-content align-self(on header)justify-item,content,self nothing working for me plz clear my confusion.

i am using visual studio. align-item align-content align-self(on header)justify-item,content,self nothing working for me plz clear my confusion

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">This is header</div>
        <div class="small-box-1">Small-Box1</div>
        <div class="small-box-2">Small-Box2</div>
        <div class="small-box-3">Small-Box3</div>
        <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
        <div class="side-bar">Side-Bar</div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To center element on the grid and avoid them to shrink, you will need to set again a grid system on your children You can use flex or grid .

**examples (might not be your grid, but needed a base that you did not provide, if that does not answer your question then, please,  clarify your question)**

- Flex can be used on the grid children to allow centering alignement.

```css
.container> div {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
  background:tomato;
  border:solid;
}

/* reconstruction of a grid */
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px,1fr);
  grid-gap:1em;
}
.container .header, .container .footer {
  background:lightblue;
  grid-column:span 4;
}

.small-box-1 {
  grid-column:2;
}
.main-content{
  grid-column:2 / span 3
}
.side-bar {
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">This is header</div>
  <div class="small-box-1">Small-Box1</div>
  <div class="small-box-2">Small-Box2</div>
  <div class="small-box-3">Small-Box3</div>
  <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
  <div class="side-bar">Side-Bar</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

- Grid can also be used on the grid children to allow centering alignement.

```css
.container>div {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  
  background: tomato;
  border: solid;
}


/* reconstruction of a grid */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.container .header,
.container .footer {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.small-box-1 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.main-content {
  grid-column: 2 / span 3
}

.side-bar {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">This is header</div>
  <div class="small-box-1">Small-Box1</div>
  <div class="small-box-2">Small-Box2</div>
  <div class="small-box-3">Small-Box3</div>
  <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
  <div class="side-bar">Side-Bar</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RanaAyaz For your next question , please add a working code so your issue is clearly seen . It will avoid downvote and closing

Comment: is there any way to do that without using flexbox. what u did i need same result.(as i said i wanna use only grid in my question)

Comment: @RanaAyaz If you do  not  want to use the flex model on the grid children, then use again the grid model. for the children . Anyhow, you need again to set a grid system to do what you want.(flex, grid or table-cell display) I proposed flex to avoid confusion from the main container display.

Comment: @RanaAyaz sorry, i do not do this. SO is full of us helping on clear question .Many good tutorials are also online. There is here all you need, for private lessons, it is not the place.

Comment: thank u for help. just for your information i learned html css , php and msql basic from tutorials in 3 months. if i get good teacher i can learn fast. i tried institutes but they r bullshit. any how thanks alot man. u guys r really helping.